# ember-cli package install failure

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I am trying to follow the ember-cli [getting started](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#getting-started) instructions but I have run into this error I can't get around.

```
~/wip $ ember new ember-test                                         [2.0.0-p353]
version: 0.0.37
installing
  create .bowerrc
  create .jshintrc
  create Brocfile.js
  create README.md
  create app/app.js
  create app/components/.gitkeep
  create app/controllers/.gitkeep
  create app/helpers/.gitkeep
  create app/index.html
  create app/models/.gitkeep
  create app/router.js
  create app/routes/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/app.css
  create app/templates/.gitkeep
  create app/templates/application.hbs
  create app/templates/components/.gitkeep
  create app/views/.gitkeep
  create bower.json
  create config/environment.js
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public/.gitkeep
  create testem.json
  create tests/.jshintrc
  create tests/helpers/resolver.js
  create tests/helpers/start-app.js
  create tests/index.html
  create tests/test-helper.js
  create tests/unit/.gitkeep
  create vendor/.gitkeep
Installing packages for tooling via npm..  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
Installing packages for tooling via npm...  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git", exit code of #128Error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git"
 exit code of #128
    at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/util/createError.js:4:15)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/util/cmd.js:99:21)

▽
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:968:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)%
```

I also run into a similar error when I run `bower install`

```
bower ember-load-initializers#0.0.2          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git", exit code of #128
```

I am working on osx maverics with npm 1.4.14, ember 0.0.37, and bower 1.3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you can run those commands manually.

When I run them, this is the output that I get

```
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89    refs/heads/master
be13fa4a45abff2c9fcfc82497668ed2a925a856    refs/tags/0.0.1
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89    refs/tags/v0.0.2
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git
603424dd74ea69f0bb4d414695b8793e71923f22    refs/heads/master
dfbf4e0b40ee1c85d5b24b892932e8bec0585fde    refs/tags/0.0.1
5265989bf429eec0f51bf512cbb1b621f492b534    refs/tags/0.0.2
```

It looks like your problem might not be to do with ember-cli, npm, or bower;
but instead to do with git.

Comment: The issue was a .git file in a parent directory that had the following. "gitdir: ../../.git/modules/cookbooks/rbenv".  Not sure how it got there but it was my junk directory so possibly from some other code.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's really pesky when the `.git` folder gets corrupted, glad that you managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that the problem was that the company firewall was blocking the required port for the git:// protocol (9418)

See https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=123246